# Accessing Kubernetes services through one IP (Master Node)

Tags: kubernetes, devops, flannel

I have a Kubernetes cluster installation with a master node and two worker nodes in centos 7 machine(On premise environment). Is there a way to access all deployed services(Built in and my micro service) that will be installed on Kubernetes through master node's ip?

I have used flannel network. My service is running on node port 30011. I am able to access my service from worker node ip and node port[192.23.12.X1:30011 and 192.23.12.X2:30011] port but I am not able to access the same service from master node[192.23.19.21:30011].

Here is my deployment and service yaml file

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: am-profile
  labels:
    app: am-profile
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: am-profile
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: am-profile
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: am-profile
        image: 192.23.12.160:8083/am-setting:1.0.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
```

service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: am-profile
  labels:
    app: am-profile
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
   - targetPort: 8081
     port: 8081
     nodePort: 30011
  selector:
     app: am-profile
```

I want to access this service like http://master-node:30011/hello.
Every help is appreciated.

Here is ip table save out put

```
-A KUBE-NODEPORTS -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/subscriber-profile-service:" -m tcp --dport 30002 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ 
-A KUBE-NODEPORTS -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/subscriber-profile-service:" -m tcp --dport 30002 -j KUBE-SVC-IUSISESM6NEI4T53 
-A KUBE-SERVICES ! -s 10.244.0.0/16 -d 10.107.113.5/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/subscriber-profile-service: cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 8082 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ 
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.107.113.5/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/subscriber-profile-service: cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 8082 -j KUBE-SVC-IUSISESM6NEI4T53 [r –
```

Comment: So you can reach the service from the Node on which the Pod is running but not any other Node? So same symptoms as https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/58908 ?

Comment: Yes I am able to access through the slave node ip where pods are running but not through other slave and master node

Answer (score 3):

If Kubernetes cluster has no network issues, you are able to access `NodePort` service using any node of the cluster including master node(s).

By default, `kube-proxy` pods create `ip-tables` rules to forward traffic from `NodeIP:NodePort` to specific `pod:port`. You can check existing `ip-tables` rules by running the following command on each node:

```
$ sudo iptables-save   
# you may need to install iptables package to use this command
# yum -y install iptables

-A KUBE-NODEPORT ... -j KUBE-SVC-... # shows you port number on the node
-A KUBE-SVC-... -j KUBE-SEP-... # shows you destination rules links and balancing
-A KUBE-SEP-... ... -j DNAT --to-destination <pod-ip:port> # shows you destination for traffic that comes to NodePort
```

If all mentioned rules are in place, check the connectivity from master to node:

```
master-node$> curl http://<pod-ip>:<port>/path-if-needed/
```

In case that check fails with a connection error, check the following:

- Are there custom firewall or firewalld rules that could drop the traffic?
- Does the cloud VPC security allow traffic between nodes?
- Is the networking solution (flannel, calico, etc) installed and working properly?
- Is the SELinux enabled?

Comment: `-A KUBE-NODEPORTS -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/subscriber-profile-service:" -m tcp --dport 30002 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-NODEPORTS -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/subscriber-profile-service:" -m tcp --dport 30002 -j KUBE-SVC-IUSISESM6NEI4T53
-A KUBE-SERVICES ! -s 10.244.0.0/16 -d 10.107.113.5/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/subscriber-profile-service: cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 8082 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.107.113.5/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/subscriber-profile-service: cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 8082 -j KUBE-SVC-IUSISESM6NEI4T53
[r`

Comment: It’s better to add important information to the question.

Comment: Is there any ip range mismatch here ? I have used --cidr=10.244.0.0/16 while initialising cluster ?

Comment: It's looks okay. You have different subnets for pods overlay network and for services' ClusterIP pool. 10.244.0.0/16 is a default pods' subnet for flannel. You can see the services subnet ( --service-cluster-ip-range ) among arguments of kube-apiserver. kubectl get pod kube-apiserver -n kube-system -o yaml