# Unable to reach service using NodePort from k8s master

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-16.04, kubernetes-service

I have setup kubernetes cluster in Ubuntu 16.04 with a master and a worker. I deployed application and created NodePort service as below.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-app-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-app
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-app
        image: yeasy/simple-web:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: hello-app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello-app
  ports:  
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30020
      name: hello-app-port
  type: NodePort
```

Pods and service are created for same

```
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP          NODE             NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/hello-app-deployment-6bfdc9c668-smsgq   1/1     Running   0          83m   10.32.0.3   k8s-worker-1   <none>           <none>

NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE   SELECTOR
service/hello-app-service   NodePort    10.106.91.145   <none>        8000:30020/TCP   83m   app=hello-app
service/kubernetes          ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          10h   <none>

NAME                                   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE   CONTAINERS   IMAGES                    SELECTOR
deployment.apps/hello-app-deployment   1/1     1            1           83m   hello-app    yeasy/simple-web:latest   app=hello-app

NAME                                              DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE   CONTAINERS   IMAGES                    SELECTOR
replicaset.apps/hello-app-deployment-6bfdc9c668   1         1         1       83m   hello-app    yeasy/simple-web:latest   app=hello-app,pod-template-hash=6bfdc9c668
```

I am able to access application from host where application is deployed as:

```bash
kubeuser@kube-worker-1:~$ curl http://kube-worker-1:30020
Hello!
```

But when I access from master node or other worker nodes it doesn't connect.

```bash
kubeuser@k8s-master:~$ curl http://k8s-master:30020
curl: (7) Failed to connect to k8s-master port 30020: Connection refused
kubeuser@k8s-master:~$ curl http://localhost:30020
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 30020: Connection refused
kubeuser@k8s-master:~$ curl http://k8s-worker-2:30020
Failed to connect to k8s-worker-2 port 30020: No route to host
kubeuser@k8s-worker-2:~$ curl http://localhost:30020
Failed to connect to localhost port 30020: No route to host
```

Created CIDR as below

```bash
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
```

The following is iptable-save result:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [30:1891]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [30:1891]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:KUBE-MARK-DROP - [0:0]
:KUBE-MARK-MASQ - [0:0]
:KUBE-NODEPORTS - [0:0]
:KUBE-POSTROUTING - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-3DU66DE6VORVEQVD - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-6UWAUPYDDOV5SU5B - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-S4MK5EVI7CLHCCS6 - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-SWLOBIBPXYBP7G2Z - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-SZZ7MOWKTWUFXIJT - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-UJJNLSZU6HL4F5UO - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-ZCHNBYOGFZRFKYMA - [0:0]
:KUBE-SERVICES - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-ERIFXISQEP7F7OF4 - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-JD5MR3NA4I4DYORP - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-NPX46M4PTMTKRN6Y - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU - [0:0]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:POST_public - [0:0]
:POST_public_allow - [0:0]
:POST_public_deny - [0:0]
:POST_public_log - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PRE_public - [0:0]
:PRE_public_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_public_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_public_log - [0:0]
:WEAVE - [0:0]
:WEAVE-CANARY - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -m comment --comment "kubernetes postrouting rules" -j KUBE-POSTROUTING
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_direct
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_ZONES
-A POSTROUTING -j WEAVE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A KUBE-MARK-DROP -j MARK --set-xmark 0x8000/0x8000
-A KUBE-MARK-MASQ -j MARK --set-xmark 0x4000/0x4000
-A KUBE-POSTROUTING -m mark ! --mark 0x4000/0x4000 -j RETURN
-A KUBE-POSTROUTING -j MARK --set-xmark 0x4000/0x0
-A KUBE-POSTROUTING -m comment --comment "kubernetes service traffic requiring SNAT" -j MASQUERADE
-A KUBE-POSTROUTING -m comment --comment "kubernetes service traffic requiring SNAT" -m mark --mark 0x4000/0x4000 -j MASQUERADE
-A KUBE-SEP-3DU66DE6VORVEQVD -s 10.32.0.3/32 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-3DU66DE6VORVEQVD -p udp -m udp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.32.0.3:53
-A KUBE-SEP-6UWAUPYDDOV5SU5B -s 10.111.1.158/32 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-6UWAUPYDDOV5SU5B -p tcp -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.111.1.158:6443
-A KUBE-SEP-S4MK5EVI7CLHCCS6 -s 10.32.0.3/32 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-S4MK5EVI7CLHCCS6 -p tcp -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.32.0.3:53
-A KUBE-SEP-SWLOBIBPXYBP7G2Z -s 10.32.0.2/32 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-SWLOBIBPXYBP7G2Z -p tcp -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.32.0.2:9153
-A KUBE-SEP-SZZ7MOWKTWUFXIJT -s 10.32.0.2/32 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-SZZ7MOWKTWUFXIJT -p udp -m udp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.32.0.2:53
-A KUBE-SEP-UJJNLSZU6HL4F5UO -s 10.32.0.2/32 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-UJJNLSZU6HL4F5UO -p tcp -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.32.0.2:53
-A KUBE-SEP-ZCHNBYOGFZRFKYMA -s 10.32.0.3/32 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-ZCHNBYOGFZRFKYMA -p tcp -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.32.0.3:9153
-A KUBE-SERVICES ! -s 192.168.0.0/16 -d 10.96.0.10/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 53 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.96.0.10/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 53 -j KUBE-SVC-ERIFXISQEP7F7OF4
-A KUBE-SERVICES ! -s 192.168.0.0/16 -d 10.96.0.10/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:metrics cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 9153 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.96.0.10/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:metrics cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 9153 -j KUBE-SVC-JD5MR3NA4I4DYORP
-A KUBE-SERVICES ! -s 192.168.0.0/16 -d 10.96.0.1/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 443 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.96.0.1/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 443 -j KUBE-SVC-NPX46M4PTMTKRN6Y
-A KUBE-SERVICES ! -s 192.168.0.0/16 -d 10.96.0.10/32 -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns cluster IP" -m udp --dport 53 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.96.0.10/32 -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns cluster IP" -m udp --dport 53 -j KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU
-A KUBE-SERVICES -m comment --comment "kubernetes service nodeports; NOTE: this must be the last rule in this chain" -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j KUBE-NODEPORTS
-A KUBE-SVC-ERIFXISQEP7F7OF4 -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.50000000000 -j KUBE-SEP-UJJNLSZU6HL4F5UO
-A KUBE-SVC-ERIFXISQEP7F7OF4 -j KUBE-SEP-S4MK5EVI7CLHCCS6
-A KUBE-SVC-JD5MR3NA4I4DYORP -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.50000000000 -j KUBE-SEP-SWLOBIBPXYBP7G2Z
-A KUBE-SVC-JD5MR3NA4I4DYORP -j KUBE-SEP-ZCHNBYOGFZRFKYMA
-A KUBE-SVC-NPX46M4PTMTKRN6Y -j KUBE-SEP-6UWAUPYDDOV5SU5B
-A KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.50000000000 -j KUBE-SEP-SZZ7MOWKTWUFXIJT
-A KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU -j KUBE-SEP-3DU66DE6VORVEQVD
-A POSTROUTING_ZONES -g POST_public
-A POST_public -j POST_public_log
-A POST_public -j POST_public_deny
-A POST_public -j POST_public_allow
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -g PRE_public
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_log
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_deny
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_allow
-A WEAVE -m set --match-set weaver-no-masq-local dst -m comment --comment "Prevent SNAT to locally running containers" -j RETURN
-A WEAVE -s 10.32.0.0/12 -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
-A WEAVE ! -s 10.32.0.0/12 -d 10.32.0.0/12 -j MASQUERADE
-A WEAVE -s 10.32.0.0/12 ! -d 10.32.0.0/12 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Aug 16 17:11:47 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sun Aug 16 17:11:47 2020
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [1417084:253669465]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [4:488]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1414939:285083560]
:FORWARD_direct - [0:0]
:INPUT_direct - [0:0]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Aug 16 17:11:47 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sun Aug 16 17:11:47 2020
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1417204:253747905]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1414959:285085300]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Aug 16 17:11:47 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sun Aug 16 17:11:47 2020
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1401943:246825511]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1401934:246824763]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [4:488]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1399691:277923964]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1399681:277923072]
:FORWARD_direct - [0:0]
:INPUT_direct - [0:0]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PRE_public - [0:0]
:PRE_public_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_public_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_public_log - [0:0]
:WEAVE-CANARY - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_direct
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -g PRE_public
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_log
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_deny
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_allow
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Aug 16 17:11:47 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sun Aug 16 17:11:47 2020
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2897:591977]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
:FORWARD_IN_ZONES - [0:0]
:FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:FORWARD_OUT_ZONES - [0:0]
:FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:FORWARD_direct - [0:0]
:FWDI_public - [0:0]
:FWDI_public_allow - [0:0]
:FWDI_public_deny - [0:0]
:FWDI_public_log - [0:0]
:FWDO_public - [0:0]
:FWDO_public_allow - [0:0]
:FWDO_public_deny - [0:0]
:FWDO_public_log - [0:0]
:INPUT_ZONES - [0:0]
:INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:INPUT_direct - [0:0]
:IN_public - [0:0]
:IN_public_allow - [0:0]
:IN_public_deny - [0:0]
:IN_public_log - [0:0]
:KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES - [0:0]
:KUBE-FIREWALL - [0:0]
:KUBE-FORWARD - [0:0]
:KUBE-SERVICES - [0:0]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:WEAVE-CANARY - [0:0]
:WEAVE-NPC - [0:0]
:WEAVE-NPC-DEFAULT - [0:0]
:WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS - [0:0]
:WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS-ACCEPT - [0:0]
:WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS-CUSTOM - [0:0]
:WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS-DEFAULT - [0:0]
:WEAVE-NPC-INGRESS - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes externally-visible service portals" -j KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES
-A INPUT -j KUBE-FIREWALL
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6784 -m addrtype ! --src-type LOCAL -m conntrack ! --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment "Block non-local access to Weave Net control port" -j DROP
-A INPUT -i weave -j WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS
-A FORWARD -i weave -m comment --comment "NOTE: this must go before \'-j KUBE-FORWARD\'" -j WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS
-A FORWARD -o weave -m comment --comment "NOTE: this must go before \'-j KUBE-FORWARD\'" -j WEAVE-NPC
-A FORWARD -o weave -m state --state NEW -j NFLOG --nflog-group 86
-A FORWARD -o weave -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i weave ! -o weave -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o weave -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding rules" -j KUBE-FORWARD
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_IN_ZONES
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_OUT_ZONES
-A FORWARD -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A OUTPUT -j KUBE-FIREWALL
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -g FWDI_public
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -g FWDO_public
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_log
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_deny
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_allow
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_log
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_deny
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_allow
-A INPUT_ZONES -g IN_public
-A IN_public -j IN_public_log
-A IN_public -j IN_public_deny
-A IN_public -j IN_public_allow
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10251 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 30000:32767 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10255 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10252 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2379:2380 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10250 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6784 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A KUBE-FIREWALL -m comment --comment "kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets" -m mark --mark 0x8000/0x8000 -j DROP
-A KUBE-FIREWALL ! -s 127.0.0.0/8 -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m comment --comment "block incoming localnet connections" -m conntrack ! --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT -j DROP
-A KUBE-FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A KUBE-FORWARD -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding rules" -m mark --mark 0x4000/0x4000 -j ACCEPT
-A KUBE-FORWARD -s 192.168.0.0/16 -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod source rule" -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A KUBE-FORWARD -d 192.168.0.0/16 -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod destination rule" -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A WEAVE-NPC -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A WEAVE-NPC -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j ACCEPT
-A WEAVE-NPC -m physdev --physdev-out vethwe-bridge --physdev-is-bridged -j ACCEPT
-A WEAVE-NPC -m state --state NEW -j WEAVE-NPC-DEFAULT
-A WEAVE-NPC -m state --state NEW -j WEAVE-NPC-INGRESS
-A WEAVE-NPC-DEFAULT -m set --match-set weave-Rzff}h:=]JaaJl/G;(XJpGjZ[ dst -m comment --comment "DefaultAllow ingress isolation for namespace: kube-public" -j ACCEPT
-A WEAVE-NPC-DEFAULT -m set --match-set weave-P.B|!ZhkAr5q=XZ?3}tMBA+0 dst -m comment --comment "DefaultAllow ingress isolation for namespace: kube-system" -j ACCEPT
-A WEAVE-NPC-DEFAULT -m set --match-set weave-;rGqyMIl1HN^cfDki~Z$3]6!N dst -m comment --comment "DefaultAllow ingress isolation for namespace: default" -j ACCEPT
-A WEAVE-NPC-DEFAULT -m set --match-set weave-]B*(W?)t*z5O17G044[gUo#$l dst -m comment --comment "DefaultAllow ingress isolation for namespace: kube-node-lease" -j ACCEPT
-A WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS -m physdev --physdev-in vethwe-bridge --physdev-is-bridged -j RETURN
-A WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN
-A WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
-A WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS -m state --state NEW -j WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS-DEFAULT
-A WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS -m state --state NEW -m mark ! --mark 0x40000/0x40000 -j WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS-CUSTOM
-A WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS -m state --state NEW -m mark ! --mark 0x40000/0x40000 -j NFLOG --nflog-group 86
-A WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS-ACCEPT -j MARK --set-xmark 0x40000/0x40000
-A WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS-DEFAULT -m set --match-set weave-41s)5vQ^o/xWGz6a20N:~?#|E src -m comment --comment "DefaultAllow egress isolation for namespace: kube-public" -j WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS-ACCEPT
-A WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS-DEFAULT -m set --match-set weave-41s)5vQ^o/xWGz6a20N:~?#|E src -m comment --comment "DefaultAllow egress isolation for namespace: kube-public" -j RETURN
-A WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS-DEFAULT -m set --match-set weave-E1ney4o[ojNrLk.6rOHi;7MPE src -m comment --comment "DefaultAllow egress isolation for namespace: kube-system" -j WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS-ACCEPT
-A WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS-DEFAULT -m set --match-set weave-E1ney4o[ojNrLk.6rOHi;7MPE src -m comment --comment "DefaultAllow egress isolation for namespace: kube-system" -j RETURN
-A WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS-DEFAULT -m set --match-set weave-s_+ChJId4Uy_$}G;WdH|~TK)I src -m comment --comment "DefaultAllow egress isolation for namespace: default" -j WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS-ACCEPT
-A WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS-DEFAULT -m set --match-set weave-s_+ChJId4Uy_$}G;WdH|~TK)I src -m comment --comment "DefaultAllow egress isolation for namespace: default" -j RETURN
-A WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS-DEFAULT -m set --match-set weave-sui%__gZ}{kX~oZgI_Ttqp=Dp src -m comment --comment "DefaultAllow egress isolation for namespace: kube-node-lease" -j WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS-ACCEPT
-A WEAVE-NPC-EGRESS-DEFAULT -m set --match-set weave-sui%__gZ}{kX~oZgI_Ttqp=Dp src -m comment --comment "DefaultAllow egress isolation for namespace: kube-node-lease" -j RETURN
```

```
weave status connections
-> 10.111.1.156:6783      failed      IP allocation was seeded by different peers (received: [2a:21:42:e0:5d:5f(k8s-worker-1)], ours: [12:35:b2:39:cf:7d(k8s-master)]), retry: 2020-08-17 08:15:51.155197759 +0000 UTC m=+68737.225153235
```

weave status in weave-pod

```
        Version: 2.7.0 (failed to check latest version - see logs; next check at 2020/08/17 13:35:46)

        Service: router
       Protocol: weave 1..2
           Name: 12:35:b2:39:cf:7d(k8s-master)
     Encryption: disabled
  PeerDiscovery: enabled
        Targets: 1
    Connections: 1 (1 failed)
          Peers: 1
 TrustedSubnets: none

        Service: ipam
         Status: ready
          Range: 10.32.0.0/12
  DefaultSubnet: 10.32.0.0/12
```

it tried solution in these links but didn't work [solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46667659/513494) and [solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53775084/513494)

Please let me know what could be the possible reason for master to not serve on the published NodePort.

Comment: There could be any number of reasons. There are some good suggestions in this thread https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/72712#issuecomment-452634765

Comment: thanks Faheem for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally, it worked it was with ports for weave wasn't open in firewall as mentioned in [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/1311)

also deleted weave deployment in kubernetes, removed /var/lib/weave/weave-netdata.db and deployed weave again, it worked.